# "You can't enable rolling updates for a single-instance environment" even when not specifying "aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

I'm trying to create a new Elastic Beanstalk environment with the EB CLI but it's failing because of an invalid option, even though that option isn't set in my config.

The command I'm running:

```
$ eb create my-new-environment -v --timeout 15
```

The error I'm getting:

```
2020-09-27 08:45:00    ERROR   "option_settings" in one of the configuration files failed validation. More details to follow.
2020-09-27 08:45:00    ERROR   Invalid option value: '1.0' (Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate', OptionName: 'MinInstancesInService'): You can't enable rolling updates for a single-instance environment.
2020-09-27 08:45:01    ERROR   Failed to launch environment.
```

But I don't have `aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate` specified in my config file!

```
# .ebextensions/settings.config

option_settings:
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:managedactions:
        ManagedActionsEnabled: true
        PreferredStartTime: "Thu:04:00"
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:managedactions:platformupdate:
        UpdateLevel: minor
        InstanceRefreshEnabled: true
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:command:
        DeploymentPolicy: AllAtOnce
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:
        EnvironmentType: SingleInstance
    aws:ec2:instances:
        InstanceTypes: t3.medium
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs:
        StreamLogs: true
        DeleteOnTerminate: true
        RetentionInDays: 1
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:
        Application Healthcheck URL: /health
    aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
        MonitoringInterval: 1 minute
```

Here's my `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml`:

```
# .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml

deploy:
  artifact: out.zip
global:
  application_name: my-application
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: null
  default_platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v2.0.2 running .NET Core
  default_region: eu-west-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: null
  repository: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

If it helps I think I did have the `MinInstancesInService` option set in a previous attempt but I've since deleted that from my config; and I have double and tripled checked that only the new version of my config is in my `out.zip` artefact.

Comment: Can you run `eb config list` and check if you have any saved configurations?

Comment: Nope, got nothing. I also double checked in the console but there are no saved configurations for my application.

Comment: What about `env.yaml` file? It can also have these settings?

Comment: I don't have an env.yaml file, I only have a config.yml file, which I've posted above

Comment: You are deploying totally new environment? Its not an existing one where you manually set its type in EB console?

Comment: Yeah, it's a new environment - though for an existing application

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-autoscalingupdatepolicyrollingupdate) that you can't set `RollingUpdateEnabled` in CLI. EB will overwrite it anyway. Maybe you can try forcing it `eb create my-new-environment -v --timeout 15 --single`?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I'm *not* setting `RollingUpdateEnabled` in the CLI, I'm *only* setting it in the configuration file, which means that it should work as expected, no?

Comment: EB CLI ignores some settings from your config files. The list of these settings is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#configuration-options-recommendedvalues). This could probably explain why they are set anyway, as EB CLI will set them by itself, regardless of your configurations.

Comment: Setting `--single` does seem to work... but then what's the point of having the `EnvironmentType: SingleInstance` option set in config if EB always overrides it anyway, either with the CLI or the console?

Comment: Not sure. Its a design choice that AWS made. But the option works in CloudFormation as I use it a lot there. If you don't mind I would like to provide an answer.

Comment: Yeah go for it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by the fact that **EB CLI ignores some settings** from the config files. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#configuration-options-recommendedvalues):

> Because the recommended values are set at the **API level**, they will **override values** for the same options that you set in configuration files or saved configurations.

The **solution** was to explicitly set the EB environment to single-instance type, using EB CLI option `--single`.

```
eb create my-new-environment -v --timeout 15 --single
```

Comment: Just to note that the question still remains that "what's the point of having the `EnvironmentType: SingleInstance` option set in config if EB always overrides it anyway, either with the CLI or the console?"

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to disable "rolling update" from AWS console by selecting the EB instance and select configuration, and then select Rolling Update, and disabled it. You can. now specify a single instance with no load balancing.

This is what I did to save some $ when the instance is deployed mostly for testing purpose or you don't anticipate much traffic on the backend.

David

Comment: TIL we need load balancing if we want "deployments without downtime" (i.e rolling updates)
If we choose single instance option in `Environment-->configuration --> capacity` , it will show error about rolling updates. So disable the `rolling updates` first and then move from `load balanced` to single `instance`

Comment: @RandString You may have a point here :-)